# Error with button on lightning-datatable: [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error

Tags: lightning-web-components

Trying to make a simple datatable with an edit button for each row, get the following error each time I press the button.

I have debugged `row.Id` to make sure the ID is passing through and even tried hardcoding but get the same error. Not sure what to do to troubleshoot further. Seems like I have followed the documentation and all the other examples on stackexchange using `NavigationMixin`

```
<template>

<template if:true={services.data}>
    <lightning-datatable 
        key-field="id" 
        data={services.data}
        columns={columns} 
        hide-checkbox-column="true" 
        onsort={updateColumnSorting}
        sorted-by={sortedBy}
        sorted-direction={sortedDirection} 
        onrowaction={handleRowAction} 
    >
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

```
    import { LightningElement,wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getServices from '@salesforce/apex/Services_Strategy.getServices';
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";

const columns = [
    {
        label: 'Assisted Services', 
        fieldName: 'Id_URL__c', 
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {
                fieldName: 'Service_Type__c' 
            },
            target: '_self'
        }
    },
    {
        label: '',
        type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Edit',
            title: 'Edit Record',
            variant: 'brand',
            name: 'editRecord'
        }
    }


   ]

export default class services_Strategy extends LightningElement(NavigationMixin) {
    columns = columns;
    @api recordId; 
    @wire(getServices, { oppId: '$recordId' }) services;

getFields({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
    }  
    else if (error) {
        console.error('Services ERROR: ', error);
    }
}

handleRowAction(event) {
    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
    const row = event.detail.row; 

    switch (actionName) {
        case 'editRecord':
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: row.Id,
                    objectApiName: 'Service__c', //I have tried with and without this line, same result
                    actionName: 'edit'
                }
            });
        break;
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For NavigationMixin, change your js file -

```
export default class services_Strategy extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    ......
}
```

You can check more on -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation

Comment: Such a silly mistake, thank you